# looking for a pair of texts in a Greek/Latin comedy

Tags: classical-latin, greek, text-corpus, greek-translation

I'm looking for any pair of texts (Ancient Greek, Latin), meeting the following criteria:

- Both texts may be very brief.
- The Latin text should be a translation very close to the Greek text.
- The Greek text should have been written between the fifth and third centuries BC.
- The Latin text should have been written by Plautus or by Terence.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Hmm do you know such a translation by Plautus or Terence exists? Or is it just your hope?

Comment: It's only a hope but I think I remember reading that some passages are obviously(?) borrowed from this or that Greek author.

Comment: I hope somebody will find something!

Comment: This edition of the fragments of Menander contains occasional references in footnotes to similar lines in the equivalent plays of Terence: https://ryanfb.github.io/loebolus-data/L132.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Plautus, *Bacchides*, lines 816-7:

> quem di diligunt / adulescens moritur
>   *He whom the gods love / dies young*

Menander, *Dis Exapatōn* (fourth century BCE), fragment quoted in Stobaeus (KT 111):

> ὃν οἱ θεοὶ φιλοῦσιν, ἀποθνῄσκει νέος.
>   *He whom the gods love, dies young.*

Neither *Dis Exapatōn* nor *Bacchides* survives completely, but the fragments we have confirm that Plautus's work is directly based off Menander's. This line would seem to be a direct quotation.

The proverb is famous now in kind of a romantic way, but in context (in both plays) the meaning is the opposite: the clever slave is making a snarky comment about a gullible old man he's just defrauded, implying that his old age means the gods *don't* love him. Either way, it seems to be one of the more famous things Menander ever wrote, which is probably why Plautus translated it so directly.